# Plotting exponential with mean

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm working on a validation script where I'm parsing out some distributions from source code and wanting to create plots. So far most of it is working, but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to supply the mean.

In java we use `org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.ExponentialDistribution` which takes a mean so we use it like this `new ExponentialDistribution(m)`

I'm using `matplotlib.pyplot` for plotting and `numpy` + `scikit.stats` for the data. But looking at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html#scipy.stats.expon I can't figure out how to supply the mean variable I parse from the code.

In short, if I parse out `new ExponentialDistrubution(5)`...how do I plot that?

If I remove all the parsing code and other irrelevant stuff my code does this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xvalues = np.linspace(stats.expon.ppf(0.01), stats.expon.ppf(0.99), 100)
cdf = stats.expon.cdf(xvalues)
plt.plot(xvalues, cdf)
plt.savefig("graph.png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html you find that to shift and scale you can use `expon.pdf(x, loc, scale)`, with `loc` being the location and `scale` the inverse of `lambda`. `scale` also corresponds to the mean, since the mean of an exponential distribution is `1/lambda`.

If you want a distribution with a mean of 5 you would write:

```
mean = 5
loc = 0

xvalues = np.linspace(stats.expon.ppf(0.01, loc, mean), stats.expon.ppf(0.99, loc, mean), 100)
cdf = stats.expon.cdf(xvalues, loc, mean)
plt.plot(xvalues, cdf)
plt.savefig("graph.png")
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not well versed in statistics, is scale always inverse of lambda? is lambda always the mean? I got desperate and searched for "mean" on the site but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Sorry. I swapped the scale and lambda. Scale corresponds to the mean and lambda is the inverse of the mean. You can see more on the wikipedia page for the exponential distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution
I have updated the answer.